# Windows Backup & Restore, network location, how to identify my machine

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-7-backup

I have a fairly decent idea of how build-in Backup & Restore works in Windows 7.  However, I need to move my machine's backups to another location, and I need help finding which files to move.  I know my machine's name is "Stormwind", and I can see the "STORMWIND" main backup folder in the network backup location, like so:

[image: 3 machines' backups including mine]

But, below those, I see a bunch of GUID-like filenames with no extension, and I am assuming these are important too.  Trouble is, I have no idea which one is "mine".  Example:
[image: 3 sample GUID-files, no idea which is whose]

Is there any way of knowing?  Or are these not at all important, and I should stop worrying about it?

Comment: no harm in backing up those also.

Comment: Trial and Error might be the best bet.  Copy the backup to the new location.  Copy one of the GUID files.  Attempt to restore a file.  Rinse and Repeat until you find the working combination.  I say to do this because there likely ISN"T another way to determine which file is for a specific machine otherwise.